# how to count the number of keys having duplicate values when the values are in a list

Tags: python, list, dictionary, duplicates, ordereddictionary

```
example_dict = {'v':['f','f','f','f','f','f','f','f'], 'c':['p','p','p','p','p','p','p','p','p'], 'a':['p','p','p','p','p','p','p','p'], 'w2' = ['f','f','f','f','f','f','f','f','f']}

#the code i have tried

flipping_example_dict = {}


for (key,value) in example_dict.items():
    if value not in flipped_example_dict:
        flipped_example_dict[value] = [key]
    else:
        flipped_example_dict[value].append[key]
```

#the error is ---> unhashable type: 'list'
#i need to find the number of keys having duplicate values. For example, the answer should be f = 2 and p = 2. This is just an example. My original dataset has appox. 1500 keys with similar problem.
#i had earlier tried to find the keys with an if statement having a condition as if value == 'p'. but it too didn't work as the values are in list and not in str.

Answer (score 0):

Error **Unhashable type: 'list'** : This is because there is a list inside your dictionary and you are trying to compare a list with a dictionary in the ***if statement***.

```
if value not in flipped_example_dict:
```

According to the problme you have explained, this code works for me.

```
example_dict = {'First_list':['F','G','F'], 'Second_list':['P','H','P','P','P']}
result = {}
for key in example_dict.keys():
    for letter in list(set(example_dict[key])):
        if letter in result.keys():
            result[letter]+=1
        else:
            result[letter] = 1
print(result)
```

Comment: Welcome. Connect on Github @aps08